# "Particular" vs. "specific"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms, collocation

The [Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com) lists *particular* and *specific* as synonyms, but there still seems to be a subtle distinction between the two. What is that distinction?

In a phrase along the lines of:

> the [particular/specific] card selected from the deck

is there any meaningful difference, or should I just use whichever sounds best?

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary has seven main definitions for *particular*, with numerous sub-headings. Much the same goes for *specific*. It all depends on the effect you are trying to achieve within the wider context. Even when words appear to be synonyms, it is often the case that they collocate differently.

Comment: There are very few (if any) exact synonyms. Synonyms don't have to replace each othe absolutely everywhere. So these two _are_ synonyms, but there are probably places where you'd prefer one over the other. But using the two together would be a pleonasm.

Comment: I'm voting to close as General Reference. In OP's *particular* context, (or *specific* - take your pick, but note that *particular* is more common), the two words are effectively synonyms. But when we're asking for more context here on ELU, we'd *always* say *"You need to be more specific"*, because *"You need to be more particular"* means you need to be more *discriminating/fastidious*. They're not ***always*** synonyms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: collocates and connotations are exactly the sort of information you **can't** look up in the dictionary. This is a very well formed word choice question that is not general reference at all.

Comment: @Marthaª: I only mentioned in passing a context where the words are used *differently*. But OP didn't ask about that - he just asked about one *highly specific* context (though I'd have to admit that even including the word *highly* immediately affects which one I could use there). My point is OP had already found a dictionary saying they're "synonyms". Which for the purposes of his example, is quite sufficient. I don't want to see ELU choked up with these kinds of question. They just generate endless rephrasings of Mitch's (perfectly true) observation, plus regurgitations from dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, whereas I think these kinds of questions are a valuable addition not just to this site, but to the internet as a whole. Please stop closing questions just because you personally don't like them.

Comment: @Marthaª: We've been here *many* times before. Please stop lecturing me.

Comment: When I have to choose between these two while writing, I use two guidelines found on this blog: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/particular-vs-specific/. Firstly, "specific" has a more formal connotation than "particular" and secondly, "specific" is recommended when the context calls for precision. Though these guidelines do not always clearly dictate which word to use, I have found them useful in many contexts.